# Adding Tkinter Tabs to Tkinter application is throwing off request aspect

Tags: python, tkinter

Hi I am working on creating simple app using tkinter that lets the user open multiple translation tabs. My single tab version works fine but my multi tab version returns nothing when the translate button is hit:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, messagebox
import requests

BASE_URL = "http://127.0.0.1:5000"

def libretranslate(text, src, dest):
    response = requests.post(f"{BASE_URL}/translate", data={
        'q': text,
        'source': src,
        'target': dest
    })
    data = response.json()
    return data.get("translatedText", "")

def translate_text(text_widget, src, dest, output_widget, translation_key):
    original_text = text_widget.get(1.0, tk.END).strip()
    if original_text:
        translated = libretranslate(original_text, src, dest)
        output_widget.delete(1.0, tk.END)
        output_widget.insert(tk.END, translated)
        translations[translation_key].append((original_text, translated))
    else:
        messagebox.showinfo("Info", "Please enter text to translate.")

def create_translation_tab(notebook, src_lang, dest_lang, translation_key):
    frame = ttk.Frame(notebook)
    notebook.add(frame, text=f"{src_lang} to {dest_lang}")

    label_input = ttk.Label(frame, text=f"Enter {src_lang} Text:")
    label_input.pack()
    text_to_translate = tk.Text(frame, height=5, width=40)
    text_to_translate.pack()

    label_output = ttk.Label(frame, text=f"Translated {dest_lang} Text:")
    label_output.pack()
    translated_text = tk.Text(frame, height=5, width=40)
    translated_text.pack()

    translate_button = ttk.Button(frame, text=f"Translate to {dest_lang}", 
                                  command=lambda: translate_text(text_to_translate, src_lang, dest_lang, translated_text, translation_key))
    translate_button.pack()

    return frame

# Main GUI setup
app = tk.Tk()
app.title("Translation Test")

notebook = ttk.Notebook(app)
notebook.pack(expand=True, fill='both')

# Translations dictionary
translations = {
    "EnglishToSpanish": [],
    "SpanishToEnglish": []  # Added another key for the second tab
}

# Create tabs
create_translation_tab(notebook, "English", "Spanish", "EnglishToSpanish")
create_translation_tab(notebook, "Spanish", "English", "SpanishToEnglish")

app.mainloop()
```

My original version:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, messagebox
import requests

BASE_URL = "http://127.0.0.1:5000"

def libretranslate(text, src, dest):
    response = requests.post(f"{BASE_URL}/translate", data={
        'q': text,
        'source': src,
        'target': dest
    })
    data = response.json()
    return data.get("translatedText", "")

def translate_text(text_widget, src, dest, output_widget, translation_key):
    original_text = text_widget.get(1.0, tk.END).strip()
    if original_text:
        translated = libretranslate(original_text, src, dest)
        output_widget.delete(1.0, tk.END)
        output_widget.insert(tk.END, translated)
        translations[translation_key].append((original_text, translated))
    else:
        messagebox.showinfo("Info", "Please enter text to translate.")

# Minimal GUI setup
app = tk.Tk()
app.title("Translation Test")

# Input text widget
label_input = ttk.Label(app, text="Enter Text:")
label_input.pack()
text_to_translate = tk.Text(app, height=5, width=40)
text_to_translate.pack()

# Output text widget
label_output = ttk.Label(app, text="Translated Text:")
label_output.pack()
translated_text = tk.Text(app, height=5, width=40)
translated_text.pack()

# Translations dictionary
translations = {
    "EnglishToSpanish": []
}

# Translate button
translate_button = ttk.Button(app, text="Translate to Spanish", 
                              command=lambda: translate_text(text_to_translate, "en", "es", translated_text, "EnglishToSpanish"))
translate_button.pack()

app.mainloop()
```

I tried curling the endpoint in the way I think the application is doing using its request method and the endpoint is working as expected.